CircleCI Parallelism messing up with time-based tests
We have a big old build that is taking too long to run tests and Im trying to setup parallelism to speed things up. After the configuration, I can see the tests are indeed running in parallel and are much faster but Im running into 2 very strange issues:

Timestamps for record are set as the same: I have this test that creates two different rows in my database with the created_at column. Later the test picks the latest created one using a order(created_at: :desc).first clause. Running locally it works as expected. Running on CircleCI with parallelism though, both created_at are set to the same value (I printed it) and the test just picks the wrong one. I know I can just also order by id desc, but I would like to understand why is that and how can I avoid it.

Tests with sleep simply doesn’t work: Again, time related, we have this class that runs a block of code and logs how long it took to run. It is as simple as the following:


 class BenchmarkLog
   class << self
     def benchmark_log(title, description, &block)
       begin
         start_time = Time.now
         yield
       ensure
         ellapsed_time = Time.now - start_time
         Rails.logger.info("#{title} - #{description} - #{ellapsed_time}")
       end
     end
   end
 end

On the test, we simply use a sleep to wait for 1s and check if that worked, like:
    BenchmarkLog.benchmark_log("MyClass", "desired operation") do
      sleep(1)
    end

    expect(log_message).to match(/MyClass - desired operation - 1/)

Oddly enough, when running locally and in CircleCI without parallelism it passes, but when running on circle CI with parallelism it fails with the message:
  expected "MyClass - desired operation - 0.0" to match /MyClass - desired operation - 1/
  Diff:
  @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
  -/MyClass - desired operation - 1/
  +"MyClass - desired operation - 0.0"

Indicating that the sleep command was simply ignored.
Im running the tests with:
circleci tests glob "spec/{services,controllers}/**/*_spec.rb" | circleci tests run --command="xargs bundle exec rspec --format progress --format RspecJunitFormatter -o ~/rspec/rspec_1.xml" --split-by=timings --timings-type=classname

So, what am I missing on the parallelism that seems to be messing up with these timings?
Thanks!

At a guess, Time.now is always returning the same time. This can happen if it is "frozen" for testing.

You can use parallel_tests to run your tests in parallel locally and debug them.

Hey @Schwern thanks, will try that... I dont think its an issue with running tests in parallel though and possibly some "misconfig" on circle ci. What you mean with Time.now always returning the same time? Why would that happen and how can I avoid it?

When doing time dependent tests, one can use freeze_time to make Time.now always return the same time. If a test did this and did not unfreeze it would affect other tests in the process. If Time.now always returned the same time, that would explain both your problems. It would appear like sleep does not work, but really it's just that start_time and Time.now are equal. If you're setting created_at using Time.now then all rows would have the same created_at.
